# How to choose power rating of a damping resistor for an LC filter?

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks, resonance, ferrite-bead

I am trying to put power filter for an SMD oscillator (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/863-power-filter-recommendations-smd-oscillators).  One concern is the LC resonance.  There are recommendations to put damping resistor in series with the capacitor like p.10 of https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-1368.pdf [image]

If so, given the current at time 0 is pretty high, say for 5V with 2ohm, power is 12.5W, which is very high and pessimistic.  How do we choose the power rating of the damping resistor?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a simulator to find your answer?

Comment: @Andyaka How can simulator tell you the power rating needed for a resistor?  At time 0, the current is very high.  If I pick a resistor for this peak current, that's 12.5W resistor, which may be too pessimistic.  That's why I try to see anyone may know how to pick one.  Thanks.

Comment: I take it that you're not familiar with simulation tools.

Comment: It might help to explain what the IN and OUT connections are, amplitudes, bandwidth, etc. Is this a megawatt industrial motor drive, or a low-level logic supply? We have no idea.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks.  I updated it.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks.  If simulation tool can do it, maybe you can share how this can be done.  Are we trying to simulate the peak current transient or something else?  I just feel the peak current may be too pessimistic.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: Alright, that clears things up a lot. Then regarding the resistor -- what resistor types are you considering, and do you know what pulse ratings (power and energy) they might handle? Have you perused datasheets, application notes, etc.?

Comment: For a practical power supply, the voltage will ramp up in 1 ms, or longer. The stress on the resistor will be minimal. You can also dampen out the oscillations by placing a 10 to 100 ohm resistor across the ferrite bead instead of the series RC dampener.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a very conservative estimate. I have guessed at some of the values, you will need to adjust them.

For startup:

Ignore the resistor for now, assume 100 microsec ramp time on your Vcc.

\$ I_c = C \frac{dv}{dt} = 10 \mu F\frac{5 V}{100\mu s} = 0.5A\$

Then calculate the peak power in the resistor:

\$ P = I^2R = (0.5^2)(2) = 0.5W \$

So, with these assumptions, I would use a 1/4 W resistor, it should be able to handle a peak power of 1/2 W.

For steady-state:

Assume that the cap is a short. I have assumed a high value of Vripple (0.1V). Note that this is the RMS value, not P-P:

\$ P = \frac{V_{ripple}^2}{R} = \frac{(0.1V)^2}{2\Omega} = 0.005W \$

If you want a more refined estimate, you should simulate it, you will need to model the ferrite bead and the input and output circuits.